# 'Cannot Decode' error when trying to save file using AVAssetExportSession when using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I ported [this example:](https://abdulazeem.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/video-manipulation-in-ios-resizingmerging-and-overlapping-videos-in-ios/) of overlaping video to Xamarin.

When i use this AVMutableComposition in AVPlayer i can watch edited video.
But when i try to save it using AVAssetExportSession i always get 'Cannot Decode' error. I tried every preset and every file type and it doesn't help.

I also tried to use official monotouch example of [AVCompositionDebugVieweriOS](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/AVCompositionDebugVieweriOS) and i get same error.

```
public AVAssetExportSession AssetExportSession (string presetName)
{
    var session = new AVAssetExportSession (Composition, presetName);
    session.VideoComposition = VideoComposition;
    session.AudioMix = AudioMix;
    return session;
}
```

When i leave session.VideoComposition as null:

```
public AVAssetExportSession AssetExportSession (string presetName)
{
    var session = new AVAssetExportSession (Composition, presetName);
    //session.VideoComposition = VideoComposition;
    session.AudioMix = AudioMix;
    return session;
}
```

The file saves without problem (but without overlay i need to have).

Anybody knows why when i use AVAssetExportSession.VideoComposition then i have 'Cannot Decode' error? Is this Xamarain/MonoTouch problem?

Comment: I have the same issue in Objective-C, with some videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I resolve this issue.
It appears that the problem was ONLY when i use iPhone simulator.
When i deploy my app to device it works fine.

Maybe this will help someone: If you have 'Cannot Decode' error in simulator, check if code runs on the device.